# How can I print a word two letters at a time? - java

Tags: java

The input is supposed to have an even length. The problem is that on the first iteration of the loop, it print Sc, but then it prints ch instead of ho. I'm not sure how to make that jump.

```
public static void twoAtATime(String a) { // School
        int len = a.length();
        if(len%2 == 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i <a.length()/2; i++) {
                    System.out.print(a.substring(i,i+1) + a.substring(i+1,i+2));
                    System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

The output is supposed to be like this:

```
Sc
ho
ol
```

Comment: increase i by 2, `i = i + 2` in the `for` loop

Comment: Hey it works! thank you. That was actually really simple.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I am just wondering, why don´t you post this as an answer, but instead only as a comment?

Answer (score 2):

To fix it:

1. Increase `i` by `2`.
2. Iterate until `i < len`.

You can improve it:

1. By calling `substring` once for two chars.
2. Using `println` with param.
3. Incrementing `i` once - `i += 2`.

After improvements:

```
public static void twoAtATime(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    if (len % 2 == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(i, i += 2));
        }
    }
}
```